# actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); Crashes Android Application When Using Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I Recently Upgraded From Eclipse To Android Studio...

I Imported My App Into Android Studio And When I Try To Run My App Through ADB, My App Crashes..

I Removed actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); From An Activity And That Activity Didn't Crash..

I Wasn't Facing This Error When I Was Using Eclipse...

Here Is The Logcat Log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

At The 33rd Line In Main Activity I'm Setting The setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled To True..

And The Theme Of MainActivity Is Not Set To Theme.NoTitleBar...

Edit : I Tried Importing More Apps But I Got The Same Error...All Of The Apps Worked With Eclipse..

Edit : Code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Line 33
```

Comment: Obviously actionbar is null.

Comment: How Could It Be Null?
It Was Working Fine In Eclipse

Comment: No idea since you didn't post code.  But you have a null pointer exception on a line where only 1 object is dereferenced.  That means that object has to be null.

Comment: It could be `null` because you changed something else when you moved to Android Studio, such as the theme, the activity superclass, versions of libraries like `appcompat-v7`, etc. In particular, if you are inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`, make sure that you are calling `getSupportActionBar()`, not `getActionBar()`.

Comment: I Tried Importing 3 More Apps Into Android Studio That Worked With Eclipse..Those Apps Were Showing The Same Error...

Comment: Check the @CommonsWare's comment. Are you using a ActionBarActivity? Post your style.